# Anotations: no permitir fechas anteriores a hoy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Campo Obligatorio*", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public string Fecha { get; set; }
```

Tengo este calendario para hacer reservaciones!
¿Cómo hago que no permita fechas atrasadas ?

Comment: Y porque no manejas esa validación en el front? Que librería estas usando?

Comment: estoy usando .net

Comment: Independiente de eso, puedes manejar esas validaciones con JQuery o alguna libreria similar ;)